# Choose and save specific SVG markers in QGIS for different text values within the same field in the attribute table

Tags: qgis-3, symbology, style, markers

I have a vector layer with different types of retail units on a map. For instance: hairdresser, baker, butcher, supermarket, etc. This information is stored within a same field column called "type" in the attributes table.

I would like to assign different SVG icons to different types of retail units but I can't find how to do this. Also, I would like to save this styling and be able to automatically reapply it to similar layers for other cities (with the exact same fields). This way, if "hairdresser" is written in the type column for a certain feature, the hairdresser icon would automatically be shown.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

To automatically load an SVG symbol based on your "type" field you can do the following:

Make sure your SVG filenames include the text you want to put in your attribute table.

Create a "type" field in your attribute table, as you say in your question.

[image]

For the layer styling:

1. Choose SVG Marker Symbol layer type
2. Click the data-defined override button for the file path and choose `Edit`

[image]

Enter an expression similar to this:

```sql
'C:\\Users\\User\\svg\\' || "type" || '.svg'
```

which constructs a file path to your saved SVGs using the value in your "type" field. (The double pipe `||` is the operator for string concatenation). Check that the preview (underlined in red) is the correct path to the corresponding SVG file.

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply, your way is even more sophisticated, in my case in the end my question was more basic as I just wanted to manually assign certain marker symbols to various features according to their type. For instance a supermarket icon for the type "supermarket" and so on. But thank you for showing that you can do so much more with this amazing software!

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer, I post it here in case someone finds it useful:
Double click on layer, in Symbology at the top of the window change "single symbol" to "categorize" (for some reason i always forget to look up), press "classify", and then you can customize by selecting the "type" attribute and choose any svg you want. If you want a circle or square background just superpose it with an icon on top. Your style can be saved and loaded for other maps.

Comment: Thank you for answering your own question! Nice one.